# Hint's Position in TextInputLayout too high

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to use TextInputLayout in my login form to make my EditText looks like this :
[image: This is what I want]

But instead, my EditText turns into this :

[image: This is my code]

The underline looks too down, and the hints looks too high
This is weird, because TextInputLayout in my other projects looks fine

I am already try adding a padding inside the EditText, but it just made the input overlap with the hints.
This is the xml for the broken TextInputLayout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/background_login"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/login_form"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:paddingStart="50dp"
        android:paddingEnd="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#641C28"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_userlogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FCC858"
                android:hint="@string/username"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/username" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_passlogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FCC858"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/password"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_btnlogin"
            android:theme="@style/btnLoginStyle"
            android:text="Sign In"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_logo"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_borderless"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit :

So, I've tried to copy the code from my previous xml just in case I missed something but the problem still there

I've already tried to make a new project and use TextInputLayout too, but the problem still unsolved

I think the problem isn't in the xml. This is my module gradle, I didn't see anything wrong here, but maybe you guys do :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.itats.huwenakapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: try using android:hint="@string/username" in TextInputLayout.

Comment: not working, it didn't change anyhting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution for this: instead of using `DrawableStart` inside `EditText`, I put the drawable in the `TextInputLayout` using this code :

```
app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/your_drawable"
```

The result is this view:

[image: ui]

As you can see, even though the underline still seems too far down, the drawable and the hint look in line with each other. This is not a perfect solution, but at least it looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"` from your EditText.

If you want the marginBottom, add it to TextInputLayout instead.

Comment: not working, margin in TextInputLayout & margin in EditText have the same effect

Comment: then review the drawables you are using

Comment: The drawable seems fine, when I tried using EditText without TextInputLayout the view looks fine
this problem only happen when I wrap my EditText with TextInputLayout